# TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones does not contain TimeZoneInfo.Local when current timezone is UTC

Tags: c#, timezone, mono

In my linux machine, where the time zone set to UTC.

```
[root@(none) /]# date
Tue Sep 22 16:11:12 UTC 2020
```

I used to run a program

```
TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local; 
      ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones ();
      foreach (TimeZoneInfo zoneVal in zones) {
          if (localZone.StandardName == zoneVal.StandardName) {
              Console.WriteLine("local zone found!!"); //this is not printing
          }
      }
```

This program works fine if I run with dotnet-core 2.1. But if I run it with mono 6.0.0.327, it is unable to find localZone in System Time Zones.

Is there any way to get it to work without changing the current timezone from UTC and without changing to dotnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StandardName` property does not identify the time zone.  It is a localized string meant for human display, and then only when daylight saving time is not in effect, and even then [sometimes they are quirky](https://codeofmatt.com/localized-time-zone-names-in-net/).

*When you want to identify the time zone, use the `Id` property, not the `StandardName`.*

Additionally:

- If you want UTC, then use `TimeZoneInfo.Utc`
- If you want the local time zone, then use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`
- If you want to find a time zone, use `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` and pass it the `Id` of the time zone you want.  The IDs will be [IANA time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) when run on Linux, and Windows time zone identifiers when run on Windows.
- If you want to write your code to be platform agnostic, then use `TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo` from my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.
- If you really need to match up `TimeZoneInfo` objects, use the `Equals` method, which compares both the `Id` and the adjustment rules (for an edge case where you might have constructed a custom time zone, or disabled DST on Windows).  See the *Remarks* section of [the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.equals?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeZoneInfo_Equals_System_TimeZoneInfo_).  For example:

  ```
  if (localZone.Equals(zoneVal))
  {
      ...
  }
  ```
- Also be aware there are differences between `TimeZoneInfo.Local` and `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id)`, especially when DST is disabled on Windows.  [See these other docs for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.local?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById  helped,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extending Matt's answer which was the one that finally helped me, below is my code snippet, the Id property is the key. You need to install the "TimeZoneConverter" NuGet. And the snippet below works in Windows & Linux with .NET Core 3.1:

```
var tz = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Any TimeZone Name");

TimeZoneInfo tst = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tz.Id);
```